# parse error in pattern

Tags: haskell, parse-error

```
count a []       = 0
count a (b:xs) = c + count a xs
  where c = case b of
          (b==a) -> 1
          (b/=a) -> 0
```

GHCI gives the error "Parse error in pattern: b == a"

I would like to know why this parse error occurs.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a == b` is not a pattern, it's an expression. As the other answer says, something like this will work:

```
case a == b of
  True  -> 1
  False -> 0
```

but that can be written more simply as

```
if a == b then 1 else 0
```

Perhaps you're thinking about pattern guards?

```
case a of
  junk | a == b -> 1
       | a /= b -> 0
```

In general, Haskell offers so many different ways to do conditional branching, it can be confusing to work out which one you need. *Patterns* are generally for when you want to decide based on which constructor is present, *or* you want to extract one of the constructor's fields into a variable for something. For *comparing* values, you generally want an if-expression instead.

Comment: Why do you need case there at all?

Comment: An alternative would be to simply use `fromEnum` to convert the `Bool` to an `Int`: `where c = fromEnum $ a == b`, at which point I'd probably just inline it to `count a (b:xs) = fromEnum (a == b) + count a xs`

Comment: Oh, god... that looks so awful.

Comment: Or just, you know, `count a = length . filter (a ==)`... The OP was asking a question about pattern syntax, not about how to implement this better. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This happens because what you have there is not pattern matching, which is what `case of` is doing. If I am not mistaken, you are only allowed to have data type constructors in there and not actual functions.

If you tried something like

```
count a (b:xs) = c + count a xs
  where c = case b == a of
      True -> 1
      False -> 0
```

it would work, but then you are better off using `if b == a then 1 else 0` instead.